# How to select in code the first item in a listview (with baseadapter) to change its background

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener, baseadapter

I have a listview for my menu with a baseadapter.

My Activity :

```
listView_menu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_menu);
model_category = new Model_Category(context);
listView_menu.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter_Menu(context, model_category.GetAllDifferentCategory()));
listView_menu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3)
        {
            view.setSelected(true);
        }
    });
listView_menu.setSelection(0);
```

My getView method of BaseAdapter_Menu (extends BaseAdapter) :

```
@Override
public View             getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View                rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null)
    {
        rowView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.customitemlistview_menu, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.category = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.category_menu);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)rowView.getTag();
    holder.category.setText(this.data.get(position));
    return (rowView);
}
```

Each item has a selector for its background with 2 differents background depending of its state (SELECTED or NOT).

When I click on an item in my listview, I set to my view `item.setSelected("true")`.

So when I click, the item's background changes, but how to change the background of the first item of my listview without clicking on it.
I have already tried 'listView_menu.setSelection(0)' but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution ! :)

In my onCreate I appy this code :

```
listView_menu.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter_Menu(context, model_category.GetAllDifferentCategory()));
    listView_menu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            ((BaseAdapter_Menu) listView_menu.getAdapter()).setPositionSelected(position);
        }
    });
```

In my BaseAdater_Menu :

I create `private int PositionSelected = 0;`

I add this method

```
public void setPositionSelected(int position)
{
    PositionSelected = position;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And I override the getView method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null)
    {
        rowView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.customitemlistview_menu, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.category = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.category_menu);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)rowView.getTag();
    holder.category.setText(this.data.get(position));
    if (position == PositionSelected)
        rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_menu_selected_background);
    else
        rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_menu_background);
    return (rowView);
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

Its a workarround but I think it works: save a variable of FisrtTime that will select the view just after creation (on BaseAdapter_Menu)

```
public BaseAdapter_Menu(...){
    ....
    mFirstTime = true;
    ....
}

public getView(int position, ...){
    .... // create your view

    if (mFirstTime && position == 0){
         mFirstTime = false;
         rootView.setSelected(true);
    }

    ... //Setup your view
}
```

Comment: I have this code to change the background :
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_menu_selected_background"></item>  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_menu_background"></item>   <!-- for other state -->        
</selector>

Comment: ok. Then just selecting the first view in your BaseAdapter_Menu constructor doesn't solve your issue?

Comment: How have a `List views` in my constructor because view are created in the gtView method.

Comment: Changed my answer. See if now helps you.

Comment: Thank you but It doesn't work :(
I don't understand why the setSelected on my firt view doesn't work !

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your `getView()` method :

```
if(position == 0) {
   rowView.setClickable(true);
   rowView.setSelected(true);
}
```

**EDIT :**

Your `Activity` should implement the `OnItemClickListener` like this :

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
```

try this in your `onCreate()` method :

```
//after setting the onItemClickListener to your listView : 
listView_menu.setOnItemClickListener(this);
listView_menu.setSelection(0);
View firstView = listView_menu.getChildAt(0);
onItemClick(listView_menu, firstView, 0, -1);
```

and extract the method `onItemClick()` to your activity :

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
     view.setSelected(true);
}
```

Comment: see my edits ; what i did in my code is just apply the code for the position 0 ( first item ) it's strange , it should work . add the xml layout of your row item

Comment: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_menu_selected_background"></item>      
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_menu_background"></item>   <!-- for other state -->        
</selector>

Comment: see my edit , (i've added `rowView.setClickable(true);`to my code. 
add the code of your layout : `customitemlistview_menu.xml`

Comment: edit your question and add the full code of your customitemlistview_menu.xml layout , and the onCreate() method of your Activity

Comment: I have a NullPointerException with the line :
    listView_menu.getSelectedView().setSelected(true);

Comment: I see your new edit, but it doesn't work. It has not a background of a selected item. I have to click on it for it to have this background.

Comment: How call the onItemClick method of my listview in my onCreate ?

Comment: just call it like what i did in my edit and tell me if it works, you just need the change the listener of your ListView to your Activity , see my edits

Comment: This line is unknow `onItemClick(listView_menu, firstView, 0, -1)` for Eclipse.

Comment: @user2033147 : see my edits, you need to extract the method onItemClick to your activity

Comment: I have a NullPointerException with the line `onItemClick(listView_menu, firstView, 0, -1)` => `view.setSelected(true)`

Answer (score 0):

**res/layout-v11/cell.xml**

If you need to develop your application only API level 11 later, All you have to do is to write like following xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**res/layout/cell.xml**

But, in API level <= 10, the above code takes crashes. So it needs like following...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**DataListCursorAdapter.java**

At second, Your adapter is needed to be notified assign of data.//...(a)

```
class DataListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private Listener mListener;
    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public TextView text;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public DataListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, Listener listener) {
        super(context, c);
        mListener = listener;
    }
    public DataListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, Listener listener, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, false);
        mListener = listener;
    }
    public DataListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, Listener listener, int flags) {
        super(context, c, FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        mListener = listener;
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        try {
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.DATA)));
            final Data data = new Data(json);
            mListener.onDataAssigned(data, view);//...(a)

            holder.name.setText(data.name);
            holder.text.setText(data.text);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name      = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.text      = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        view.setTag(holder);
        return view;
    }
    public interface Listener {
        public void onDataAssigned(Data data, View view);//...(a)
    }
}
```

**YourFragment.java or YourActivity.java**

you implement the interface and ...

```
@Override
public void onDataAssigned(Data data, View view) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.equals(mLastSelectedDataId, data.id)) {// default color
        view.setBackgroundColor(0xfff7aecb);
    }
    else {// selected color
        view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    }
}
```

you keep the selected item on the field of your class.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    Cursor cursor = mArrayCursorAdapter.getCursor();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.DATA)));
    final Data data = new Data(json);
    if (data != null && TextUtils.equals(mLastSelectedDataId, data.id)) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, false);
        mLastSelectedDataId = null;
    }
    else if (data != null) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        mLastSelectedDataId = data.id;
    }
}
```

**Important**

- On the list view, the number of item views is not the number of item.
- The selected view, which is changed color, is reused for another data.

**Update**

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Listener mListener;
    private Model_Category mData;

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView category;
    }
    public YourAdapter(Context context, Model_Category data, LayoutInflater inflater, Listener listener) {
        mInflater = inflater;
        mListener = listener;
        mData = data;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return /*return count*/;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return /*return item by position*/;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return /*return id by position*/;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customitemlistview_menu, null);
            holder.category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_menu);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        mListener.onDataAssigned(mData.get(position), convertView);//...(a)
        holder.category.setText(mData.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }
    public interface Listener {
        public void onDataAssigned(Data data, View view);//...(a)
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work and I have a BaseAdapter and not a CursorAdapter.

Comment: This code is actually running on my own application.
It's no matter what you use BaseAdapter or any other Adapters.
When a list item data is assign, it needs to determine that the data is already selected or not and change color of list item view.

Comment: Can you tell me how use your code with my BaseAdapter please, thank you.